# Does every Linux fd have a buffer?

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel

After the client connects to the server, the input on the server terminal will be blocked until the client disconnects. Is this blocked data in the terminal's buffer?
What happens if the input data is larger than the terminal's buffer?

There is a similar buffer in the tcp stack. When the application does not process the data in the buffer, tcp will adjust the window size so that the sender no longer sends data. Is there such a mechanism for the terminal?

Does every Linux fd have such a buffer? Is the size of the buffer determined by the implementation?

```
void echo(const clientinfo &ci){
    size_t n;
    char buff[MAXLEN];
    rio_t rio;
    Rio_readinitb(&rio,ci.fd);
    while((n = Rio_readlineb(&rio,buff,MAXLEN)) != 0){
        std::cout << "server received " << n  << " bytes from "<< ci.client_hostname << " port " <<ci.client_port  <<std::endl;
        std::cout << buff;
        Rio_writen(ci.fd,buff,n); 
    }
}

void command(){
    char buf[MAXLEN];
    if(!fgets(buf,MAXLEN,stdin))
        return;
    std::cout << buf;
}
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int listenfd,connfd;
    socklen_t clientlen;
    sockaddr_storage clientaddr;
    fd_set read_set,ready_set;
    clientinfo ci;
    if(argc != 2){
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <port>" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    listenfd = open_listenfd(argv[1]);
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&read_set);
    FD_SET(listenfd,&read_set);

    while(1){
        ready_set = read_set;
        if(select(listenfd+1,&ready_set,NULL,NULL,NULL) < 0)
            unix_error("select error");
        if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&ready_set))
            command();
        if(FD_ISSET(listenfd,&ready_set)){
            clientlen = sizeof(sockaddr_storage);
            ci.fd = accept(listenfd,(sockaddr*)&clientaddr,&clientlen);
            getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&clientaddr,clientlen,ci.client_hostname,MAXLEN,ci.client_port,MAXLEN,0);
            std::cout << "connect from " << ci.client_hostname << " port " << ci.client_port <<std::endl;
            echo(ci);
            close(ci.fd);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: File descriptors do not have buffers. Libraries like the C library provide buffers.

Comment: Yes, but every fd has a buffer associated with it

Comment: Why do you ask, if you know it?

Comment: I am not sure if my understanding is correct

Comment: Depends on the driver.  Serial ports typically buffer 8 or 16 chars in hardware.  Some realtime audio code does not buffer to avoid latency.  Network devices may have fairly large packet buffers.  So it is not guaranteed that all fds have buffers.

Answer (score 1):

A [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) gets created by the kernel for a process. Typically this is done with [`open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html). `open` associates a process specific number, the file descriptor, with a device, managed by the kernel.

After that the process can read data from its file descriptor. This is usually done with [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) or [`recv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html). Both system calls write into a buffer. Does this mean that the file descriptor owns the buffer, which is part of the memory of the process? I do not think so.

But the fact that `read` writes into a buffer is typically not meant, when people talk about buffers. Usually people talk about the [pipe buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer), which is managed by the kernel, if two processes talk to each other. Each process has its own file descriptor and in between sits the buffer. Does this mean that the buffer is owned by one of the two file descriptors? I do not think so either.

But YES: Buffers are everywhere. Hardware devices are buffering. Device drivers are buffering. The kernel caches (buffers) memory pages. Pipes buffer. The C library buffers. User mode programs buffer.

And NO: There is not a buffer, there are many.